# Trying to Copy column and paste into another sheet based on another cells value VBA

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to copy the content of a column only if another cell equals "Yes". If the cell equals "Yes", I want to paste the selected columns range into another workbook. Then loop to the next "Yes".

```
    If M2 = "Yes" then copy AD2:AD200 if "NO" go to the next "if"
    If M3 = "Yes" then copy AE2:AE200 if "NO" go to the next "if"
    If M4 = "Yes" then copy AF2:AF200 if "NO" go to the next "if"
```

and so on....

The last one i will look for is M11.

Then paste the copy range to last blank cell in sheet "Cases in QA Status",

```
    range("AL200",range("al200").end(xlUp).select
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    If Range("M8").Value = True Then
    Range("aj2:aj200").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Cases in QA Status").Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M8").Value = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("aj2:aj200").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Cases in QA Status").Range("A1")
End If
```

And repeat for other columns :).

Naturally if you have "Yes" in the column, then replace `True` with `"Yes"`.

Comment: @GhiaHoldren if you are satisfied with any answer: you can mark one best answer and vote up any number of helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Copy Method

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, rngDB As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set toWs = Sheets("Cases in QA Status")
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("m2", .Range("m" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If vDB(i, 1) = "Yes" Then 'vDB(i, 1) = True then
            Set rngDB = Ws.Range("ad2").Resize(199).Offset(, i - 1)
            Set Target = toWs.Range("al" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rngDB.Copy Target
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

### 2. Using Array

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vData As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set toWs = Sheets("Cases in QA Status")
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("m2", .Range("m" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If vDB(i, 1) = "Yes" Then 'vDB(i, 1) = True then
            vData = Ws.Range("ad2").Resize(199).Offset(, i - 1)
            Set Target = toWs.Range("al" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Target.Resize(199) = vData
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```